# More elegant way to return index of a list

Tags: c++, nested-class

I am writing a circle-list in C++. Here is my code

```
class CList
{
private:
    class ListNode
    {
    public:
        int v;
        ListNode *prev;
        ListNode *next;
        /*constructor*/
    };
    ListNode *_tail;
public:
    typedef const void* const Index;//need a way to represent something like 'index' or 'position'
    CList():_tail(0)
    {

    }
    void print()const;
    void insert(Index pos, const int &value);
    Index find(/*some condition*/);
};
```

The nested-class `ListNode` is just used to implementation, so I don't want user of `CList` can access `ListNode`. But as it is a list, user can insert new node in some position, so I add the member `Index`(the Index should not be modified!). But it is stupid and I have to cast it to `ListNode*` manually. Is there an elegant way to do this? or using a nested-class is just a mistake at the begging.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes any sense at all.  If I provide you an "Index", which is actually a pointer to a `ListNode`, I already have access to it.  I can maintain the pointer and mutate it as I please.  Hiding it behind a `void*` does't change anything.  You should simply have an `Insert(const T& value)` and create the node yourself internally.  You can then have a `T Find(const T& value)`.  Of course, you could just use a `std::list` and be done with it.

Comment: But User can not see the nested private class `ListNode`, you can not cast it to `ListNode*`.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical C++ way for dealing with positions in containers is, of course, to use iterators. An iterator could hold, internally, a pointer to your `ListNode` and use the dereference `operator*()` and `operator->()` to provide access to the element at the given position. Two iterators would be comparable to determine if they point to the same location (i.e., to the same internal `ListNode`). Aside from the `find()` operation, the `insert()` operation could also provide an iterator. ... and, of course, an `erase()` member could use an iterator to remove the element.

To fully support `find()` you'll also need some sort of indicator, e.g., a singular iterator pointing to null rather than to a `ListNode`, to indicate that the element wasn't found.

Comment: Yeah, I have already thought about iterator. It is too heavy to do within this simple implementation. I have to think about it again. Maybe `iterator` is just what I have to go.